# can't make msdropdown disabled

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new at jquery . 
I'm using [msDropDown plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) which a plugin that makes a dropdown lsit with image and description and I'm facing a problem with making a msdropdown list disabled and then remove this attribute !! 
I've tried :

```
 $('#id').attr('disabled',true);
```

and

```
 $('#id').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

and

```
 $('#id').attr('disabledAll','disabledAll');
```

and

```
$('#id').addClass('disabled');
```

and

```
$('#id').addClass('disabledAll');
```

and

```
$('#id').disableSelection();
```

I'm out of solutions ! can any one helps me :(

Comment: Hi Sally, this question is off topic here and belongs on StackOverflow. (Admins will move it, so don't double post there).

Comment: ok sorry, but nobody answered me

Comment: This is very specific question about a plugin. Please look at this [issue](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown/issues/52) for this plugin for more info. Also for further questions like this please find the repository for that plugin and search if some issues like you face is there or not, else post a bug there and not ask here.

Comment: @thorstenmüller there is not need to move this question to any other place, there is a similar bug issued for the plugin previously. guess this can be closed now.

Comment: I asked on the plugin site but the author is not answering .
there's no forum to disguess my problem .

Comment: can't you just fix this bug yourself? and give him a pull request?

Comment: if you are ok to change the plugin itself, you can look at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) it is having a [healthy commit activity](https://github.com/ivaynberg?tab=contributions&period=monthly) too.

Comment: thanks but i finished coding finally :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you're using would work on a normal dropdown (`<select>`) element, but the plugin works in such a way that it creates new markup to *emulate* dropdown behaviour — it no longer supports native form element properties, so setting the `disabled` attribute has no effect on it.

However, the plugin does expose its own disabled property — it just isn't triggered the same way. [The documentation](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/examples/help.html) could be clearer, but it says that you can use the `.set()` method to modify properties. Taking that into account, the code should be:

```
$('#id').data('dd').set('disabled', true);
```

…or, if it hasn't been initialized yet:

```
$('#id').msDropDown({disabled:true});
```

Comment: thanks !! I don't know why I didn't recognize the .set() function .
here's the syntax if other person fell in my problem :
var c=$('#id').msDropDown().data('dd');
c.set('disabled', true)

Comment: You could have linked to [the documentation](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/examples/help.html)

Comment: @Shikiryu I did — the words 'The documentation' in the answer above are linked to it. The same way you did.

Comment: @Barney oooops my bad, I should change my lenses ;)

Comment: @Shikiryu the `:visited` link style on StackOverflow isn't differentiated enough, if you ask me. I didn't realise your comment linked to it either at first glance.